# Json parsing with no image url

Tags: android

How to parse a image from a JSON web service which has no image url,only image name and image extention is there.

{

"Image":"ABC.jpg"

}

Answer (score 2):

Hello welcome to stackoverflow.

You need to append base URL to string like `"http://server"` and pass it to imageURL.

Like :

```
String url ="http://server/";

// In your parsing   
url =url +json.getString(Image);
```

Comment: :thank you...may this will help...

Comment: You solve your issue ?

Comment: solved...lazy adapter+your method...

Comment: Great.. Congratulations. Accept answer and close it. Thanks.